# Hibernate validator set messages from enum instead of passing string

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate data validator as below way

```
public class CustomerDTO {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide valid type")
    private String type;
}
```

Above code is working fine but it's a tight couple.

Another way is for getting messages from properties file like below

```
public class CustomerDTO {

        @NotEmpty(message = "${notempty.type}")
        private String type;
}
```

> But If need to put messages from enum then it's not working and saying
>
> ```
> The value for annotation attribute NotEmpty.message must be a constant expression
> ```

Using enum code look like

```
@Data
public class CustomerDTO {

    @NotEmpty(message = ErrorCodeEnum.INVALID_SUB_TYPE.getErrorCode())
    private String type;
}

Enum :

public enum ErrorCodeEnum { 
    INVALID_SUB_TYPE("1002","Please provide valid type");

    private final String errorCode;
    private final String errorMsg;

    private ErrorCodeEnum(String errorCode, String errorMsg) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return errorMsg;
    }
}
```

How to resolved that?

Comment: Move the error message to a property file and initialize the enum with said property file, so the actual error message is not tightly coupled to the Entity or enum but rather to the property file.

Comment: Why it's througing exception